# How to specify query depth of Spring data neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Spring Data Neo4j provided a way to specify the query depth:

```
@Depth(value = 2)
List<KNode> findByName(String name);
```

But it's hardcoded, is there any other ways to specify the depth as an argument of the method just like:

```
List<KNode> findByName(String name, int depth);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to annotate the parameter.

```
List<KNode> findByName(String name, @Depth int depth);
```

Find more here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference_derived-queries